# The function returns nil

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I'm a beginner, I wrote a function that checks if in the request `pagination.Main == true` , then the function returns `prod`, otherwise `prod_2`. The default parameter is `main == true` , but if I change it to `false` I get `"data": null`

My funcs:

```
func GetAllIproducts(q *models.Products, g *models.Products_2, pagination *models.Params) (*[]models.Products, *[]models.Products_2) {
    var prod []models.Products
    var prod_2 []models.Products_2
    offset := (pagination.Page - 1) * pagination.Limit
    if pagination.Main {
        if pagination.Cat_id == nil {
            config.DB.Model(&models.Products{}).Where(q).Limit(pagination.Limit).Offset(offset).Find(&prod)
        } else {
            config.DB.Model(&models.Products{}).Where(q).Where("cat_id IN (?)", pagination.Cat_id).Limit(pagination.Limit).Offset(offset).Find(&prod)
        }
        return &prod, nil
    } else {
        if pagination.Cat_id == nil {
            config.DB.Model(&models.Products_2{}).Where(g).Limit(pagination.Limit).Offset(offset).Find(&prod_2)
        } else {
            config.DB.Model(&models.Products_2{}).Where(g).Where("cat_id IN (?)", pagination.Cat_id).Limit(pagination.Limit).Offset(offset).Find(&prod_2)
        }
        return nil, &prod_2
    }
}
```

```
func GetAllProducts_by_multi_params(c *gin.Context) {
    pagination := GenerateMultiParams(c)
    var prod models.Products
    var prod_2 models.Products_2
    ProdLists, _ := GetAllIproducts(&prod, &prod_2, &pagination)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "data": ProdLists,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second return value is hold by the underscore _ in

```
ProdLists, _ := GetAllIproducts(&prod, &prod_2, &pagination)
```

You can change it to `Prod2Lists` and check for nil, like:

```
ProdLists, Prod2Lists := GetAllIproducts(&prod, &prod_2, &pagination)
If ProdLists != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "data": ProdLists,
    })
} else {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "data": Prod2Lists,
})}
```

Comment: This won't work, i have error:  cannot use &prod_2 (value of type *[]models.Products_2) as *[]models.Products value in return statement

Comment: i see, them may be change the _ in `ProdLists, _ := GetAllIproducts(&prod, &prod_2, &pagination)` to Prod2Lists. The &prod_2 value is hold by the _